# How do I run a server on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to link to localserver:3000 on ruby on rails but when I use bundle exec rails server, it just exits and doesn't generate the server.

```
➜  demo git:(master) ✗ bundle exec rails server
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    Exiting
```

This is my route.rb if it helps!

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root "pages#home"
end
```

I created a controller called pages and created a view called home. When I first generated the server, I already ended the session so I'm wondering how I can generate the server again so I can see my "home" page.

This is what happens when I try to get the server. Can anyone explain to me what could be wrong? Thank you!

Edit:
I created my controller by using

```
bundle exec rails g controller pages
```

Then I added home.html.erb under views.

I managed to connect to the server but this is the error I see on my page:

[image]

I ran the command but nothing happened. I copied and pasted

```
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

and this was what I got:

[image]

Comment: That's all of the output? No scary error message?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah that was it )-:

Comment: Can you run rails console?

Comment: show your config for Puma server.

Comment: Aren't you daemonizing the server?

Comment: How did you create the application? What have you changed so far? Can you reproduce the steps? And to rule out other factors: does this also happen when creating a new Rails application?

Comment: @Stefan Updated the post! And no, this doesn't happen with new applications. I just don't know how to run the server again in an existing application.

Comment: @guymil, migrations are pending, run -> rails db:migrate

Comment: @guymil The big red error message tells you exactly what command to run. Have you tried running it?

Comment: @TomLord yeah I ran it already, look at the update

Comment: What do you mean by _"nothing happened"_ – an error message is not nothing ;-) BTW, could you post the whole error message / output, please?

Comment: @guymil Error messages are there for a reason -- you need to read them. What does it say? Post the whole error here; don't cut it off before the important part. Maybe your database is misconfigured? Maybe there's a syntax error in the migration? Maybe the database is in an inconsistent state, and you should recreate it? Maybe the migration is invalid, e.g. you're trying to create a table that already exists? I don't know what's wrong, because you're not showing us -- again, please post the **full** error message.

Comment: The problem is your user migration. Please post your migrations here so that we can help you pinpoint where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the status of all your migrations, maybe there is another migration pending. Use this command `rake db:migrate:status` to see all migrations status.

You can also reset your db and do the migrations all over again. 
`rake db:reset` (which runs `db:drop` then `db:setup`) then run your migrations `rake db:migrate`.

Also, please check if any of your migrations are referencing on any other migration that is still not created!

P.S. Please add the complete error you are getting, so I can have a better idea what the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I think either of this should be the problem.

1. You cloned the files that was built on Mac to run on windows or Vice versa.
2. There are some queries you cannot pass to the database. Pending the type of database, you are using with your Rails application.
3. Crosscheck if your database settings are correct.

That's it, Try this.
1. For rails, 5+ do `rails db:rollback`

2. `Bundle install` (just to see if everything works well)
3. Run `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`. if it still doesn't work, Look through the error report on your terminal, you should be able to see the things that are resisting the "migrate" command.
4. start your server with rails s --port=PORT_NUMBER. (e.g `rails --port=4000`)

Comment: There should be no need for a rollback as the failed migration is the first (and probably the only) migration.

Comment: I think he should. he might have run multiple times before asking for help. Well, if he's working with Postgres, it'll  be very necessary to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the `db/migrations/20180619074210_create_users.rb` file. Delete it as the migration already failed. You do not need to undo it ([rollback](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back)).

Also, I would highly recommend using command line to create a migration file until you are familiar with them. And if you have time, checkout Rails guides for [Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

**Example:**

1) Create a `user` table with `name` column (`string`) and `age` column (`integer`):

```
rails generate migration CreateUsers name:string age:integer
```

2) This will create a similar file with a different timestamp. In my machine I got `db/migrate/20180626151529_create_users.rb`.

3) If you open that file, you can examine the changes:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :age
    end
  end
end
```

4) If all looks good, you need to **run** this migration file. That can be achieved by:

```
rake db:migrate
```